# how i can create a model and insert array data into sqlite flutter

Tags: flutter, sqlite, dart

hi im new in flutter im creating a project that contains array data in one attributes , im trying to save it to may local device using sqlite but want to store the value of the array not in form of json data i don't have any clue how to make a perfect model for this api may problem is how i can create a model that will save all the values in array any idea will be appreciated please see the json data below.

[image: sample json data]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this model will be useful for you;

```
class DoctorModel {
  String doctorID;
  String doctorCode;
  String doctorFirstName;
  String doctorLastName;
  String doctorFullName;
  Map<String, dynamic> rcvc;

  DoctorModel(this.doctorID, this.doctorCode, this.doctorFirstName, this.doctorLastName, this.doctorFullName, this.rcvc);

 DoctorModel.fromMap(Map snapshot)
    : doctorID = snapshot['DoctorID'] ?? '',
    doctorCode = snapshot['DoctorCode'] ?? '',
    doctorFirstName = snapshot['DoctorFirstname'] ?? '',
    doctorLastName = snapshot['DoctorLastname'] ?? '',
    doctorFullName = snapshot['DoctorFullname'] ?? '',
    rcvc = snapshot['rcvc'].cast<Map<String, dynamic>>() ?? {};

 toJson() {
   return {
  "DoctorID": doctorID,
  "DoctorCode": doctorCode,
  "DoctorFirstname": doctorFirstName,
  "DoctorLastname": doctorLastName,
  "DoctorFullname": doctorFullName,
  "rcvc": rcvc,
  };
 }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the help bro very appreciated, but can you explain a little bit for this code thank you

Comment: Of course, when you bring data with json, you will send it to this method in the form of a map. After that, you can call the method from anywhere and access the data.
Here is example code usingMethod(){
  Map<String, dynamic> snapshot = {}; //code where you pull json data
  DoctorModel doctorModel = DoctorModel.fromMap(snapshot);
  print(doctorModel.doctorID);
  print(doctorModel.doctorFirstName);
  print(doctorModel.doctorLastName);
  print(doctorModel.doctorCode);
  print(doctorModel.doctorFullName);
}